# Problems with SIG WINCH

Tags: linux, window, size

When I run this command in a Linux terminal (konsole) and change then the windows size nothing happens.
I have a second Linux in a virtual machine. There it works as expected.

```
trap -- 'echo changed size' SIGWINCH
```

What could be the reason that `SIGWINCH` doesn't work any more?

__

Example: when I run this script on a normal Linux it outputs "SIGWINCH!" and dies as soon as the windows is resized. On the problem Linux resizing the windows has no effect - the script keeps running.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$SIG{WINCH} = sub { die 'SIGWINCH!!!' };

my $sum;
for my $i ( 1 .. 10_000_000 ) {
    printf "%0.3f\n",  $i / 31;
}
```

---

SIGWINCH is working again. I don't know why.

Comment: Can you show us more of the problem script? It matters what is running (`sleep` shell builtin intercepts signals) when the window changes size. See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28820/issue-with-winch-signal-what-am-i-overlooking

Comment: Does it work in other terminals?

Comment: With `xterm`, it also does not work.

Comment: My suspicion is that it has something to do with `wine`.

Comment: What shell and terminal emulator are you using on both machines? What distribution and what version? Do you have the same configuration files?

Comment: @Gilles On both machines (one is 64-bit and one 32-bit): openSUSE 13.1 GNU bash 4.2.45(1) Konsole 2.11.3. I suspect that wine changed some configuration files but I don't know which one have influence on the behavior of SIGWINCH.

Comment: @sid_com It could be something in the terminal emulator configuration or in the shell configuration. Wine does not affect either.

Comment: @Gilles It is working again. I don't know why. There were some updates - maybe they fixed it.